# Creating A Program in JCreator

Tags: java, jcreator

Would any of you know how to do this program , look below for the description

"Write a program which will let a bank customer log in and view their details, withdraw money, lodge money and change PIN.  Have arrays storing names, pin numbers, account balances and overdraft. The arrays must be updated when the user lodges or withdraws money or changes a PIN. The PIN cannot be a PIN that is already in use. The user can only withdraw more money than they have in their account if they have an overdraft."

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to tell you how to do it, but I can give you some advice. You are probably going to want to make a `BankAccount` class with instance fields for their details and methods for viewing details, withdrawing money, etc. Frankly, using static arrays is a stupid way of doing it. If your teacher allows it, just make a static array of `BankAccount`s and access the fields directly:

```
    BankAccount[] accounts = new BankAccount[20]; //as big as you need
    //initialize it here
    //to access the PINs, do something like this:
    int i = BankAccount[i].getPIN();
```

Finally, to make sure the PINs are never duplicated, inside the constructor search through the array for matching PINs and handle a match as necessary.
That's a lot of information, and I sense you are new to Java. Feel free to ask me any questions.